# Apply edge detection on image array

Tags: python, sobel

I am trying to do edge detection in below code:

```
lfw_people = fetch_lfw_people(min_faces_per_person=70, resize=0.4)

# introspect the images arrays to find the shapes (for plotting)
n_samples, h, w = lfw_people.images.shape

# for machine learning we use the 2 data directly (as relative pixel
# positions info is ignored by this model)
X = lfw_people.data
n_features = X.shape[1]

# the label to predict is the id of the person
y = lfw_people.target
target_names = lfw_people.target_names
n_classes = target_names.shape[0]

print("Total dataset size:")
print("n_samples: %d" % n_samples)
print("n_features: %d" % n_features)
print("n_classes: %d" % n_classes)



###############################################################################
# Split into a training set and a test set using a stratified k fold

# split into a training and testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X, y, test_size=0.25)
```

I am trying to use sobel for edge detection, but as per my knowledge sobel is used on 1 image. How I can apply it on multiple image or array of images?

Answer (score 0):

I believe asking on http://dsp.stackexchange.com or maybe http://datascience.stackexchange.com (to me it sounds like you are rather unclear about the features you are trying to extract) would be better choices for this question.

Comment: How I can pre-process an array of image using sobel edge detection. In above code: 'X' we are storing all images how can I apply sobel on X as it consist of multiple images.